# Status Bar overlaps Navigation Bar in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I'm currently working on an iOS Project, I am using a scrollView for swipe Navigation between two ViewControllers like below:

[image]

But when I Scroll to the "ViewController2" the status bar overlaps the NavigationBar.

[image]

How Can I Fix That ?

I have already done multiple research, but there is no topics which treat this specific case (Navigation Controller embed in UIScrollView)

Comment: What do you have in your info.plist, in View controller based statusbar ?

Comment: @SamuelD : I have "View controller-based status bar appearance" set To "NO" and "Status bar is initially hidden" set to "YES"

Comment: But why do want a navigation controller in a scrollview? I think it would be the other way around

Comment: @Oritm I use navigation controller because i have multiple views relative to the settings that are embed in parents views etc..

Comment: Maybe you're better of with a container view controller, in there you can use a navigation controller

Comment: Is the NavigationBar from your NavigationViewController or did you set it up yourself?

Comment: @M.Kremer The navigationBar is by default with the "NavigationController"